# How can I access to the DAnnotation eoi of a Diagram (Elements of Interest) with M2DOC

Tags: m2doc

Using M2DOC with Sirius Services in CAPELLA workbench, I would like to identify among diagrams (only those not Contextual) which ones are related to other elements of the CAPELLA models.

For that I would like to access to the DAnnotation eoi (Elements of Interest) when I'm using the sirius service: "representationByDescriptionName".

How should I proceed? Is it possible from this Sirius service?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Annotations seems to be added to the DReprestationDescriptor and not the DRepresentation itself.

You will need to create a Java service:

```
public DRepresentationDescriptor getDescriptor(DRepresentation representation) {
  return new DRepresentationQuery(representation)getRepresentationDescriptor();
}
```

Then you can use it this way in your template:

```
{m:myDiagram.getDescriptor().eAnnotations->select(a | a.source = 'http://www.polarsys.org/capella/dannotation/ContextualElements').references}
```

You will have to change the URI to select "Elements of Interest".

Comment: Thank you. I'm a M2DOC user but not a developers then how I can create this new service and add to my M2DOC project?

Comment: You will need to create an Eclipse plugin then create a Java class with the given method. Then you will need to build it an install it in your Capella.I'll add this service to M2Doc, use the nigtly build.